# Como hago para acumular variables?

Tags: c

soy nuevo en esto pero trato de aprender.

Que hace el programa: Hice un programa calculadora que suma, resta, divide y multiplica, el programa se mantiene realizando operaciones hasta que el usuario elija no continuar, pulsando "n".

Mi pregunta es: que tendría que hacer si yo quisiera que el programa acumule todas las respuestas, sin importar la cantidad de operaciones que haya hecho y las muestre como resultado acumulado solo cuando el usuario elija pulsar "x"

Aqui mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    char salir_continuar, caracter;

    do
    {
          printf("\n s) Suma");
          printf("\n r) Resta");
          printf("\n m) Multiplicacion");
          printf("\n d) Division");
          printf("\n\nElija una opcion: ");
          scanf("%c", &caracter);

  switch(caracter){

     case ('s'): printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
             scanf("%d", &a);
             printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
             scanf("%d", &b);

             printf("\nEl resultado Final: %d",a+b);
             break;


     case ('r'): printf ("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
                  scanf("%d", &a);
                 printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
                  scanf("%d", &b);

                  printf("\nEl resultado Final: %d", a-b);
                  break;



    case ('m'):   printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
            scanf("%d", &b);

            printf("\nEl resultado de Final es: %d",a*b);
            break;



    case ('d'): printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
            scanf("%d", &b);

            printf("\nEl resultado de Final es: %d",  a/b);
            break;


    default: ;

}

     printf("\n\n quiere hacer otra operacion matematica? ...");
     printf("\n\n elija n para salir o s para continuar: ");
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%c", &salir_continuar);

    system("cls");

    }while(salir_continuar!='n');

   printf("\n Hasta luego");

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ten una variable que guarde los resultados.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "resultado acumulado"? Si se trata solo de sumar todos los resultados previos, basta que tengas una variable, digamos `acumulador` inicializado con 0 y que tras cada operación hagas `acumulador += resultado`. Si lo que quieres en cambio es tener una lista de todos los resultados previos la cosa es mucho más compleja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comentan... Puedes crear una variable que te permita guardar en cada iteración de tu `do-while` el resultado de cada operación. Te recomiendo además que trates esos resultados con variables en coma flotante (`float`, `double`...) para evitar redondeos y que tengas mayor precisión. Recuerda también que en tu función de `printf` puedes establecer el número de decimales que quieres mostrar.

Tu código quedaría algo parecido a esto. Observa que he creado 2 variables tipo `float`. Una llamada `resultado` que almacena en resultado individual de cada operación, y otra llamada `valor_acumulado` que permite ir guardando sucesivamente el valor del resultado obtenido junto con los anteriores.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    char salir_continuar, caracter;
    float resultado, valor_acumulado = 0;
    do
    {
          printf("\ns) Suma");
          printf("\nr) Resta");
          printf("\nm) Multiplicacion");
          printf("\nd) Division");
          printf("\nx) Muestra total");
          printf("\n\nElija una opcion: ");
          scanf("%c", &caracter);

          switch(caracter){
    
             case ('s'): 
                printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
                scanf("%d", &a);
                printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
                scanf("%d", &b);
                resultado = a+b;
                printf("\nEl resultado Final: %f", resultado);
                break;
    
             case ('r'): 
                printf ("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
                scanf("%d", &a);
                printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
                scanf("%d", &b);
                resultado = a-b;
                printf("\nEl resultado Final: %f", resultado);
                break;
    
            case ('m'):   
                printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
                scanf("%d", &a);
                printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
                scanf("%d", &b);
                resultado = a*b;
                printf("\nEl resultado de Final es: %f", resultado);
                break;
    
            case ('d'): 
                printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
                scanf("%d", &a);
                printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
                scanf("%d", &b);
                resultado = a/b;
                printf("\nEl resultado de Final es: %f", resultado);
                break;

            case ('x'):
                printf("El valor acumulado de las operaciones es %f", valor_acumulado);
                break;
            
            default: 
                printf("Opcion incorrecta\n");
                break;
        }

     printf("\n\n quiere hacer otra operacion matematica? ...");
     printf("\n\n elija n para salir o s para continuar: ");
     fflush(stdin);
     valor_acumulado += resultado;
     scanf("%c", &salir_continuar);

    system("cls");

    } while(salir_continuar!='n');

   printf("\n Hasta luego");

   return 0;

}
```

También, como comenta @abulafia, si lo que quieres es guardar todos y cada uno de los resultados dados, deberías creas una matriz de variables en coma flotante e ir guardando cada uno de ellos en una posición mediante una variable contador que incrementes sucesivamente dentro de tu `do-while`. ¿El tamaño? Lo podrías definir como parámetro de entrada dado por el usuario al comenzar el programa, o si quieres que esté indefinido deberías jugar con la memoria dinámica. No creo que este sea tu problema, pero no está de más explicarlo.

Comment: Los tipos `float`, `double`, etc. también tienen errores típicos, que no se corresponden directamente con lo que llamamos comunmente redondear, pero se les dice redondeo igual. Sería bueno aclarar que eso pasa.

Comment: Al final todos tienen errores. Obviamente `float` tiene la mitad de bits de información que un tipo `double`. Lo único que decía es que para operaciones (sobretodo división) es fácil que el resultado sea decimal, y trabajar con enteros hace que pierdas mucha información. Gracias por el apunte de todos modos.